# Sum Indirect Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a series of table that breakdown the users per product usage. I have also created a summary table. In the summary table i want to sum the total number of users on a for each product using the product name to dynamically search there designated table. The product tables are created using the product name with the exception that spaces have been replaced with "_". For Example `DynCRMSrvcPrvdr ALNG LicSAPk MVL SAL` will have a table name `DynCRMSrvcPrvdr_ALNG_LicSAPk_MVL_SAL`

For some reason when i try the reference the table and sum column 'count' i get an error

`=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(E4," ","_")&"["&Count&"]"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "COUNT" column header name should as well be within the quotation marks. Please try the corrected formula:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(E4," ","_")&"[Count]"))
```